# Text Label inside Qt EllipseItem

Tags: c++, qt, graph, ellipse

Just started with Qt today and already got a problem. I want to place a text inside a `QGraphicsEllipseItem` but there seems to be no `setText()` or `setLabel()` function. It should be just one word in the middle of the ellipse. The ellipse is movable, so the text should move aswell when the ellipse gets moved. Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to create a separate text and update its position after moving the ellipse? Hope there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsEllipseItem` is an element which you can place to a `QGraphicsScene`.
There is also a `QGraphicsTextItem` - an element for displaying text on a `QGraphicsScene`.

So I think you should subclass `QGraphicsEllipseItem` and add to it `QGraphicsTextItem` to display your text.